# What is a REST-3002 error on TigerGraph mean?

Tags: graph, tigergraph

Where are error codes for TigerGraph located? We have a have a 3002 error code when running an GSQL.

Answer (score 2):

REST-3002 means “TIMEOUT set by system”. If there is more specific detail about your error instance, it would have been displayed on stdout/stderr or written to a log file.

If you need to increase the timeout duration, have a look at the [documentation on RESTPP request](https://docs.tigergraph.com/dev/restpp-api/restpp-requests#size-and-time-limits).

We will publish the information on error codes shortly.

Comment: Thanks - I was guessing it had to do with a timeout!